# I thought PHP required semi colons?

Tags: php

I recently upgraded my servers (local WAMP and production boxes to PHP 5.4) and am cornfused with the usage of semi-colons, I'm not complaining I have no love for the ; but don't get how this code runs locally and on a production box with no errors and error reporting is set to E_ALL...

I thought I needed a ; after `<? phpinfo ?>`<-- apparently not!

This does not generate an error either: `<? print_r(apache_get_modules()) ?>`

This works without semi-colons as well: `<? foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) printf("%s:%s \n", $name, $value, PHP_EOL) ?>`

All of this code doesn't gen an error and while like the omission of my friend the ; I am wondering WTF is happening?

Is is because of my PHP 5.4 version or do phpinfo, print_r and printf not require semi colons?????

All of this code runs with no errors:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="tab_one"><pre>Server Variables: <? print_r($_SERVER) ?></pre></div>
    <div id="tab_two"><pre>Server and PHP interface: <?= PHP_SAPI ?></pre></div>
    <div id="tab_three"><pre>Apache Modules: <? print_r(apache_get_modules()) ?></pre></div>
    <div id="tab_four"><pre><?= apache_get_version() ?></pre></div>
    <div id="tab_five"><pre><? foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) printf("%s:%s \n", $name, $value, PHP_EOL) ?></pre></div>
    <div id="tab_six">
        <p><a href="/server-status?refresh=3" target="_blank">Server Status</a></p>
        <br />
        <p><a href="/server-info/" target="_blank">Server Info</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Cornfused?

Comment: I'm cornfused as to what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

According to ["Instruction Separation" in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php):

> The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a semicolon; you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block.

Comment: I checked google but the results were varied...


I was 95% certain that if it wasn't a shorthand echo <?= {something} ?> semi-colons were implicitly required (at least in PHP 5.2.X)...

Has something changed in PHP 5.3 or 5.4?

Appreciate the response!

Comment: @BillJobs: Oh, you did Google? O.K., then, +1. :-) As for the PHP version . . . I'm not sure whether older versions of the PHP Manual are available online, but I have access to a machine running PHP 5.2.17, and `<? echo "foo" ?>` works just fine there. And I don't see anything about this in [the PHP 5 Changelog](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php).

Comment: ruakh, Great reply. Sarcasm must be your primary programming language, good job, great, well done. Super, thanks so much. Well done, cheers. Awesome, Epic work. You're doing great work and are a valued contributor on Stack Overflow. Awesome. Keep it up!

Comment: @BillJobs: I actually wasn't being sarcastic. By "+1" I meant that I was upvoting your question, which until that point I hadn't done because of your seemingly not having Googled. (The question originally seemed very ambiguous on the "shows research effort" condition for upvoting.)